# API Proxy Server

Tags: ember.js, nginx, proxy, ember-data, ember-cli

I'm using ember-cli. Need to make calls to remote server, I don't have control over the API, and CORS is not setup on the API.

I am struggling with getting a proxy server setup. Ideally I would love to use something built into ember-cli. I have seen the proxy option "ember serve --proxy" but I can't figure out how to use it.

I basically want to do:

```
Ember.$.ajax('https://www.somewhere.com/api/v1/data/plans', {
            "type": 'POST',
            "dataType": 'JSON',
            "data": {
                "name": "My delivery plan",
                "date": "2013/11/20",
                "distance_unit": "mi"
            }, // End data payload
            "success": function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                return data;
            },
            "error": function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                window.console.log(jqXHR);
            }
        });
```

When I do this I get:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.somewhere.com/api/v1/data/plans. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Also looking into nginx, but I have no idea how to set this up locally or how to get it to work with the ember-cli server.

Any help is much appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm thinking `nginx` is the way to do this, and you can [follow along with this open pull request here](https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-cli/pull/637) for some insight into how it can work.

I'll try to update this answer when I get something more comprehensive, but it should serve as a good starting point.